# Trello responds 'invalid key'

Tags: node.js, trello, node-https

I am trying to get JSON data for a Trello board using the following URL, using Node.js's `https` module:

> [`https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.json`](https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.json)

Here's my code:

```
var https = require('https');

https.get('https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.json', function (res) {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:');
    console.log(res.headers);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
});
```

Although the URL works perfectly in browser, It returns a body containing the string "invalid key", with a 401 status. Following is the output:

```
statusCode: 401
headers:
{ 'cache-control': 'max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15768000',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-trello-version': '1.430.0',
  'x-trello-environment': 'Production',
  'set-cookie':
   [ 'dsc=ae78a354044f982079cd2b5d8adc4f334cda679656b3539ee0adaaf019aee48e; Path=
     'visid_incap_168551=/NYMaLRtR+qQu/H8GYry1BCKl1UAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAC1zWDD1JLPowdC
     'incap_ses_218_168551=+/2JSB4Vz0XJO/pWbX4GAxCKl1UAAAAA0pAbbN5Mbs4tFgbYuskVPw
  expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '12',
  etag: 'W/"c-b1ec112"',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  date: 'Sat, 04 Jul 2015 07:24:00 GMT',
  'x-iinfo': '1-11281210-11279245 PNNN RT(1435994639565 404) q(0 0 0 -1) r(3 3) U
  'x-cdn': 'Incapsula' }
invalid key
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it turns out that we need to provide a Trello API application key (generated from [here](https://trello.com/1/appKey/generate)) with our request.

```
var https = require('https');
var KEY = '<replace this with your app key>';

https.get('https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ.json?key=' + KEY, function (res) {
    ...
});
```

This seems to me a weird requirement because we are not using Trello's [API endpoint](https://trello.com/1/). (Even if I solved the problem, I would still like to know why a browser can access the resource, but a server side script cannot.)

Comment: It may not look like it, but we handle that as being part of our API.  Requests that look like they're coming from a browser and are for public resources are exempted from the app key requirement, so that public boards load correctly.

Comment: "Requests that **look like they're coming from a browser**". Oooooooooh! I think I might know what to do. @AaronDufour, I think you should restrict usage on things like requests per IP inside a temporal window. It's not hard to forge a request to look like it's coming from a browser.

Comment: We do rate limit by IP.  You should just pass an app key.  Why do you think forging a browser request is a better solution?

Comment: @AaronDufour: I don't necessarily think forging a browser request is *better*. But someone *can* do it. I'll try it for science but I'm definitely not doing it on my app.

Comment: I'm trying to embed a Trello board in a page for personal use. But `/b/nC8QJJoZ.html` or `/b/nC8QJJoZ.js` are useless for me because they don't get instantly updated. So I created a simple angular app which uses `/b/nC8QJJoZ.json`. But `/b/nC8QJJoZ.json` does not support CORS. And I can't embed a Trello app key in my angular app; I don't want users to see the key. So I'm forced to make a simple proxy to get the JSON and serve it to my app. That's how I encountered the problem.

Comment: App keys are not necessarily secret.  Most client apps expose them.  I wouldn't worry about it.  If you want CORS, you should use the `/1/` API - `/b/:id.json` just makes a call into the API with particular arguments.