# How can red be used to connect to REST apis?

Tags: rest, red

I found that there is a red command to download contents of a web page:

```
read https://trello.com/c/8p75OiSE/26-test-card.json
```

However, I have two problems (at least on Linux Mint):

1. Trello's response differs for this request than it does for simply [visiting this URL](https://trello.com/c/8p75OiSE/26-test-card.json) in a web browser (try it! it works fine in a browser).
2. If I did need to add authorization headers (shouldn't for this public card), I don't see a way to do that.

It is even worse in [Tio.run](https://tio.run/##K0pN@f8/KDVFITqWi6soNTFFIaOkpKDYSl@/pCg1JydfLzk/Vz9Z36LA3NQ/M9hV38hMtyS1uEQ3ObEoRS@rOD/v/38A), but I'm pretty sure that is not a problem with the language itself but with Tio.run.

Comment: On point 1—I get the same response from Trello. Is it different perhaps as you're signed in to Trello in the browser?

Comment: @rgchris you get an error response? I tried in private browsing too and it worked.

Comment: Here's some code to [talk to Trello in Rebol2](http://www.codeconscious.com/rebol/articles/basic-trello-interface.html), which may be of interest, but probably hasn't been checked for operation with recent Trello.

Comment: @NH. No—I didn't get an error response.

Comment: This shows a comparable issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218141/trello-responds-invalid-key

Answer (score 3):

WRITE, and more specifically WRITE/INFO should give you enough leverage to engage most APIs.

The most basic usage of WRITE returns the body of the HTTP response:

```
probe write http://some.resource/api/method "Some Data"
```

You can get the header of the response by adding /INFO:

```
probe write/info http://some.resource/api/method "Some Data"
```

And you can send different HTTP methods and headers using a BLOCK! as your WRITE argument:

```
probe write/info http://some.resource/api/method [
    put [Content-Type: "application/json"] {["Some Data"]}
]
```

Comment: For more help with `write`, check out [rebolek/http-tools](https://github.com/rebolek/red-tools/blob/master/http-tools.red) on Github. He also has REST API wrappers around Github and Gitter there.